# Duplication of class inside two different objects

Tags: python, class

I found a bug in my program and I did some digging before making something much simpler to understand the problem.

In a nutshell: I'm creating two objects from a class where I want to store an object from another class. But When I'm doing this, both objects are getting the same result. How can I prevent this duplication?

It seems like both objects are pointing on the same class.

```py
# Sub-class that may not be extendable
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    @classmethod
    def add_number(cls, number=0):
        return cls(number)

# Main class
class MyOtherClass:

    my_objects = []

    """
    Initialize the class
    :param List[MyClass] my_objects: List of MyClass objects
    """
    def __init__(self, this_object):
        self.my_objects.append(this_object)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    my_object1 = MyOtherClass(MyClass.add_number())
    my_object2 = MyOtherClass(MyClass.add_number())

    for i in range(100):
        my_object1.my_objects.append(MyClass.add_number(i))
        print(f"Appending obj1 : {my_object1.my_objects[i].number}")

    for y in range(100, 0, -1):
        my_object2.my_objects.append(MyClass.add_number(y))
        print(f"Appending obj2 : {my_object2.my_objects[y].number}")

    # later

    z = 0
    while z < len(my_object1.my_objects):
        print(f"obj1 : {my_object1.my_objects[z].number}")
        print(f"obj2 : {my_object2.my_objects[z].number}")
        z += 1
```

Comment: `my_objects` is referencing the list on the class `MyOtherClass`. Inside `MyOtherClass` make a new list for every instance. `def __init__(self, this_object): self.my_objects = [] ...`

Comment: I was looking at this problem for hours when it was so obvious! Thanks a lot. I understand the problem way better now. Thanks a lot!